# System can't enter to Ubuntu flash progress to flash BIOS after I updated the kernel to v5.19.0 under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, updates, flash

In my Ubuntu 22.04 the kernel version of Ubuntu was v5.15.0. I updated the kernel version of Ubuntu to v5.16.0 or later by manual to check this issue. I found when the Ubuntu kernel was less than v5.19.0 and Ubuntu version was 22.04 and secure boot was disabled, I test flashing system firmware via fwupdmgr. The system can enter to Ubuntu flash progress to flash BIOS like the below picture.

[image]

After I updated the Ubuntu kernel to v5.19.0, I used the same way to flash system firmware via fwupdmgr. The system can't enter to Ubuntu flash progress to flash the BIOS and boots to a recovery page like the below picture.

[image]

Comment: Yes. I used Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I had updated the kernel to v5.18.19 by manual.

Comment: I don't see anything related to Ubuntu here - only screenshots of UEFI menus.

Comment: I only updated Ubuntu kernel to v5.19.0 and other settings were the same as the previous test. System embedded firmware and new system embedded firmware were the same as the previous test.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. You state that you updated your device's BIOS, and now you cannot boot beyond the BIOS. Is that correct?  It would seem that the BIOS rev is the issue. Can you rollback to the prior BIOS instance? I'm trying to understand how Ubuntu (or any OS) would be part of the problem.

Comment: No, I tested Ubuntu fwupdmgr function. I used two device's BIOS to test it and system could boot to Ubuntu with the two device's BIOS. One is the old BIOS version, the other is the new BIOS version. Only the BIOS version is different from the two device's BIOS and the content of the old device's BIOS is the same as the content of the new device's BIOS.